# facing problem while convert byte array to bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-studio, native

**my code**

```
 String passenger_sign = assignedJobJson.getJSONObject(position).getString("passenger_sign");
        Log.e(TAG, "passenger_sign: "+passenger_sign );


        byte[] Bytedata = passenger_sign.getBytes();
        Log.e(TAG, "Bytedata: "+Bytedata );

        ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Bytedata);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(arrayInputStream);
        //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Bytedata, 0, Bytedata.length);
        Log.e(TAG, "bitmap: "+bitmap );
```

**problem**

1. i want to convert byte array to bitmap but it showing only null value while converting to bitmap.

Comment: did you checked that your byte[] itself is null or not?

Comment: i checked it, it a byte array.
passenger_sign: [91,66,64,56,55,57,56,57,102,57]

Comment: i got a byte array value

Comment: it contains byte array in a string format.

Comment: FYI: not every byte array can be converted to bitmap. Only bitmap byte array. (the one having corresponding headers, etc.). Show the value of your JSON

Comment: passenger_sign: [91,66,64,56,55,57,56,57,102,57]

this is my json value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `passenger_sign` contains the image data converted in Base64, you can apply the following code:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(passenger_sign, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
// Now, we set the decoded bytes to an image view to check if conversion is successfull
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Comment: im using that also it showing the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Comment: You can try to decode the byte array in this way:

`Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Bytedata, 0, Bytedata.length);`

Comment: i do that too bro, it showing the same exception which i told u before.